# Unexpected horizontal lines between cells in ListView

Tags: flutter

I have render's issue when using ListView: there are horizontal lines from ListView's background(its parent).

Minimal code to reproduce:

```
  Widget _buildTestWidget() {
    return Container(color: Colors.blue,
      child: ListView(children: <Widget>[
        for(int index = 0; index < 100; ++index)
          Container(height: 30, color: Colors.red)
      ]),
    );
  }
```

The result looks like this:

[image]

As you can see there are red containers and blue lines between them - parent container is partially visible. I expected to see the whole red screen, without the background.

How to fix it if it's possible?

Answer (score 0):

Its something that's being cause due to the `height` attribute you're specifying. If you remove that and just put the child, like `child: Text("")`, it removed the lines

Comment: Thanks, but it isn't a solution for me as I have the same issue with much more complex widgets, I cannot just remove height attribute. This simple code just reproduces that I have in a more complex case.

Comment: Whenever you reload the page, it doesn't show the lines. The lines appear after scrolling

Comment: It's an issue of the render system, I understand how to solve it if I was using OpenGL for example, but I don't understand how to do it in Flutter using easy ways :)

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is automatic. I had the same issue on my app using a *ListView.builder*. The only fix I found was to set the background color of my scaffold to the same color of the container.

Comment: I have cells of different colors in my app :) So this is not a solution for me

Comment: Ok, I can't help you then, I'm not sure this is possible in fact. I think that each ListView is separated by 1px. There are several ways to use custom dividers ( for example by using the _separatorBuilder_ property of _ListView.separated_ widget ) but you will still have the same issue.

Comment: No, there is no 1px, this the feature of the render system. Thanks for the answer!